# What is the difference between borderBottomStartRadius and borderBottomLeftRadius in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, mobile

As the title states it would be better if someone can explain the difference between these two, since both of these props the same thing to an element.

I tried googling but i did not get any leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of these definitions depends on the direction of the layout of the app. The `start` and `end` meaning changes depending on the layout of the applcation

When the layout of app is Left to Right :

- **borderBottomLeftRadius** : radius of bottom-left corner
- **borderBottomStartRadius** : has no significance

When the layout of app is Right to Left :

- **borderBottomStartRadius** : radius of bottom-left corner
- **borderBottomLeftRadius** : has no significance

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, i just tested this theory out and it checks out.